# OnFormClosing WindowsShutDown cancel

Tags: vb.net

Short question, below see my OnFormClosing method which i use. Can you please explain me what this line do and where its gonna be true:

```
 If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.WindowsShutDown Then
            Return
        End If
```

and whole method:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosing(e As FormClosingEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)

        If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.WindowsShutDown Then
            Return
        End If

        If lsbxPicPaths.Items.Count > 0 Then
            e.Cancel = True
        Else
        End If
        ClearPicsTempFolder()
    End Sub
```

Comment: It will be true if the operating system is being shutdown.  I.E Shutting the pc down or restarting. When you do this the operating system closes all open applications. If this is the case that code will exit the sub and do nothing more.  If its not it will continue to the next statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `CloseReason` enumeration specifies the reason that a form was closed and `WindowsShutDown` occurs when operating system is closing all applications before shutting down.

So don't do extra work (cancel form closing if a list of pics is populated and clear temp folder) if a windows shutdown is closing your application.